# How can I add document which has base document with 2 lines in SDK, SAP B1?

Tags: sapb1

I have a problem of base document,

I tried to add document which has base document with 1 line or row in php it works fine,

But if base document has more than 1 row it does not work, if I try to add the second row, I get error message Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www............

```
$oOrder->Lines->Itemcode="A001";
$oOrder->Lines->Quantity=1;
$oOrder->Lines->UnitPrice=200;
$oOrder->Lines->BaseType="1470000113";
$oOrder->Lines->BaseEntry=7;
$RetCode=$oOrder->Lines->Add;

$oOrder->Lines->Itemcode=A002;
$oOrder->Lines->Quantity=2;
$oOrder->Lines->UnitPrice=300;
$oOrder->Lines->BaseType="1470000113";
$oOrder->Lines->BaseEntry=7;
$RetCode=$oOrder->Lines->Add;
$RetCode=$oOrder->Add;
```

As it seems the second row does not allow BaseEntry and BaseType fields

How can I add document which has base document with 2 lines in SDK?

Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It misses the `$oOrder->Lines->SetCurrentLIne` after the first `Add`.

`Lines` is a collection of `Line` and adding a row in it doesn't change the index.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second `$RetCode=$oOrder->Lines->Add;` just before the Add of the order.

When you create a new order object, you get a blank 'Lines' object ready to be populated, so you only need one `Lines->Add` for a two line order. The extra one you have at the end is making a three line order with the last line being unpopulated.